# QML TableView + QAbstractTableModel - how edit model data from QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have C++ class inherited from QAbstractTableModel with next functions overriden:

```
virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const noexcept override;
virtual Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex& index) const noexcept override;

virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const noexcept override;
virtual int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const noexcept override;
virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const noexcept override;

virtual bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) noexcept override;
virtual bool insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) noexcept override;
virtual bool setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& data, int role = Qt::EditRole) noexcept override;
```

model has 3 columns, first is readonly, last is editable, so this is flags() method implementation:

```
Qt::ItemFlags ObjectInitialStateModel::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const noexcept
{
    if (index.column() == 0)
    {
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren;
    }
    else
    {
        return Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemNeverHasChildren;
    }
}
```

In QML part model is displayed fine, but i have no idea how i can edit model data for 2 and 3 columns in TableView. I've tried to write column delegate:

```
Item {
    id: item
    state: "labelMode"

    Text {
        id: textLabel
        text: styleData.value
        anchors.fill: parent
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering
    }

    TextField {
        id: textField
        text: styleData.value
        anchors.fill: parent

        Keys.onEnterPressed: commit()
        Keys.onReturnPressed: commit()
        Keys.onEscapePressed: rollback()

        function commit() {
            item.state = "labelMode"
        }

        function rollback() {
            item.state = "labelMode"
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onDoubleClicked: item.state = "editMode"
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "labelMode"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: textLabel
                visible: true
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: mouseArea
                visible: true
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: textField
                visible: false
            }
        },

        State {
            name: "editMode"
            PropertyChanges {
                target: textLabel
                visible: false
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: mouseArea
                visible: false
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: textField
                visible: true
                focus: true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but i don't know how to set new data to the model in commit() function correctly.
Or may be there are another right way to implement table in QML with editable columns and C++ model?

Answer (score 3):

I've found one solution:

1. add property to the delegate:

---

```
property var cppModel
```

---

2. set this property in column definition:

---

```
TableViewColumn {
    role: "u"
    title: qsTr("u(t)")
    width: initialStateTableView.width / 3
    delegate: EditableDelegate {
        cppModel: DataSetService.currentDataSet ? DataSetService.currentDataSet.initialStateModel : null
    }
}
```

---

3. implement new method in C++ model:

---

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool setData(int row, int column, const QVariant& data) noexcept;
```

---

which calls default setData method

4. and call it from commit() function in delegate:

---

```
function commit() {
    cppModel.setData(styleData.row, styleData.column, text)
    item.state = "labelMode"
}
```

---

But i think this is **big ugly hack** and if anybody knows more elegant solution, please share it...

Comment: Not very pretty, yes. If TableView works like ListView (which I never tried) you can write into `styleData.value`: `styleData.value = text`. That should result in a setData() call in the model width the correct index set.

Comment: Anton:  2 years now. Any idea for more elegant solution ?

Comment: I've switched to PyQt and classic widgets after some time of having troubles with QML.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the `roleNames()` and `data()`, the editable models must reimplement the `setData()` function to save changes to existing data. The following version of the method checks if the given model index is valid and the role is equal to `Qt::EditRole`, before executing the actual update. Depending on the model you can/must also call the parent class version of the function:

```
bool EditableModel::setData(const QModelIndex &item, const QVariant &value, int role)
  {
      if (item.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole) {
          // update logic
          emit dataChanged(item, item);
          return true;
      }
      return false;

  }
```

It should be noted that unlike the C++ item views, such as `QListView` or `QTableView`, **the `setData()` method must be explicitly invoked from QML whenever appropriate.**