# QAbstractTableModel subclass representation in qml

Tags: qml, qt5

I created QAbstractTableModel subclass for represent it's like a table in Qml. When in qml i used GridView, or ListView items, they used only first column to represent. According to documentation : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html this classes uses QAbstractListModel. Is there any class, to correct representation QAbstractTableModel in qml, like a Grid?

There is .h file of my Model (All functions below are implemented in C++)

```cpp
class ButtonModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum ButtonRoles {
        BUTTON_ID_ROLE = Qt::UserRole + 1,
    };
    enum ColumnNames{
        FIRST = 0,
        SECOND,
        THIRD,
        FOURTH,
        FIFTH,
        SIXTH,
        SEVENTH,
        LAST
    };

    ButtonModel(QObject* parent = 0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole);
    bool loadModel (const QVector<QHash<ColumnNames, Button *>> &buttons, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex());
private:
    QVector<QHash<ColumnNames, Button*>> _buttons;
};
```

And data() function implementation

```cpp
QVariant ButtonModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if ((!index.isValid()) || (this->rowCount() <= index.row()) || (this->columnCount() <= index.column())){
        return QVariant();
    }
    switch (role){
        case ButtonRoles::BUTTON_ID_ROLE:
            return QVariant(_buttons[index.row()][ColumnNames(index.column())]->buttonId());
            break;
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(_buttons[index.row()][ColumnNames(index.column())]->displayText());
            break;
        default:
            return QVariant();
    }
}
```

Comment: How many columns / rows are you expecting? This might influence the design. I think your best choice is to use a ListView where delegate contains multiple columns, reading data from different roles of a QAbstractListModel, or from different properties of a QList<QObject*> model

Comment: There are 4x8 table. Yes, i will use QAbstractListModel +GridView/GridLayout pair.

Comment: To be clear, I am not recommending gridview or gridlayout. I do not think either are a suitable approach for creating a table. I am suggesting a ListView with a RowLayout in the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a QTableView not a QGridView.

A grid view is really just a different layout for a list, whereas a table view does have multiple columns and can take its model data from a C++ QAbstractTableModel.

[TableView QML Type | Qt Quick Controls 5.9](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html)

Comment: A `TableView` can't take its model data from a `QAbstractTableModel`.  Like `ListView` and `GridView`, it uses roles and not columns to query the data of a model.

Comment: I skim-read various examples so I could  be wrong. But e.g. [c++ - QML TableView + QAbstractTableModel - how edit model data from QML? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332298/qml-tableview-qabstracttablemodel-how-edit-model-data-from-qml) suggests that it can. Or is some adaptation from columns to roles taking place?

Comment: I don't know how the code in the question you linked can work if uses columns and not roles. You can't specify to display a specific column index in `TableView` or `TableViewColumn`.

Comment: Yes TableView can use QAbstractTableModel. You just need to convert rolenames to column numbers in the data() and setData() methods. But be careful ... the TableView gets really slow with a lot of data in it. TableView is basically an abandoned component from Qt Quick Controls 1. There is one in development for Quick Controls 2, but it is taking a long time and still not available in Qt 5.9